# React async useEffect with loading and error state

Tags: javascript, react.js, asynchronous, redux

This is my first time trying to add clean error handling and loading notification for async requests in my project. It looks kind of bulky to me, but maybe that's because I'm inexperienced? This is what I have at the top of all my index-like components. I also thought maybe it was a good target for a custom hook, but I haven't made any before.
`getClasses` is a Redux thunk action, and `classes` also comes from a Redux slice of state.

```javascript
const ClassIndex = ({ classes, getClasses }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClasses = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError("");
        await getClasses();
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError("There was an error finding your classes.");
      }
    };
    fetchClasses();
    return () => {
      setError("");
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
  }, [getClasses]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For async requests I suggest you to use  [**react-query**](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) package. Which return you `isLoading` and `isError` for per request. And you don't need to create additional local state.

With react-query I can reduce all of your code just to 4 lines.

```
  const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery('key', async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('link')
    return res.data
  })
```

`isLoading` flag need to be converted to true in `finally` case. Then we just remove unnecessary `setIsLoading(false);` in `catch` and after `getClasses` request

```
    const fetchClasses = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError("");
        await getClasses();
      } catch (error) {
        setError("There was an error finding your classes.");
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchClasses();
```